# How to return array of objects from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays:

```
a1= ['All', 'one', 'two'];

a2= ['Users', 'Service', 'Admin'];
```

I need to return an array of object like this

```
[
{value: 'All', label: 'Users'},
{value: 'one', label: 'Service'},
{value: 'two', label: 'Admin'}
]
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Loop over the array indexes. Then push the object containing the values from each array at that index onto the result array.

Comment: How would you do it? This works better when you try to solve the problem first and interact and learn from the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const a1 = ['All', 'one', 'two'];
const a2 = ['Users', 'Service', 'Admin'];

a1.map((item, index) => ({
    value: item,
    label: a2[index]
}))
```

Comment: Don't do people's homework for them, they'll never learn.